# ¿Cómo saber si los textos tratan de temas concretos, dados de antemano?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

Intento conectar las frases con los temas. He intentado hacerlo con un ejemplo sencillo y BERT:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import numpy as np

# Modèle BERT
model = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')

# Textes de référence
texts_ref = ['Le positionnement de marque est essentiel pour la notoriété assistée',
             'Le Wine Brand Power Index est un indicateur de la notoriété de la marque',
             'La segmentation par pays d\'origine et par âge est importante pour le marketing']

# Keywords à rechercher
keywords = ['metteurs en marché', 'Volume monde']

# Embeddings des textes de référence et des textes à comparer
embeddings_ref = model.encode(texts_ref, convert_to_tensor=True)

# Embeddings des mots clés pertinents
embeddings_keywords = model.encode(keywords, convert_to_tensor=True)

# Similarité cosinus entre les embeddings des textes et des mots clés pertinents
cos_similarity_ref = np.dot(embeddings_ref, embeddings_keywords.T)

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(cos_similarity_ref, columns=keywords, index=texts)
```

Pero obtengo una cosa extrana: para la frase que contiene *metteurs en marché* (`Les salariés et les vendangeurs sont des metteurs en marché`) obtengo la peor puntuación mientras que `Le volume des ventes de vin a augmenté de 20% dans le monde` obtenga el mejor. Ademas `Volume monde` obtiene 56.432217 mientras que no esta mencionado.

```
                                                                        metteurs en marché  Volume monde
Les salariés et les vendangeurs sont des metteurs en marché 33.560791   56.432217
La ventilation par circuits est différente entre les Discounters allemands  33.254173   85.759445
Le volume des ventes de vin a augmenté de 20% dans le monde 85.039169   86.833595
```

Comment: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10459

Answer (score 0):

En el ejemplo que proporcionaste, el modelo BERT está siendo utilizado para calcular la similitud entre los textos de referencia y los textos a comparar. Los embeddings de los textos de referencia y los embeddings de las palabras clave pertinentes se utilizan para calcular la similitud coseno entre ellos 2.

Es posible que el modelo BERT no haya sido entrenado para reconocer analogías o metáforas en el texto, lo que podría explicar por qué obtiene una puntuación baja para la frase que contiene “metteurs en marché”. Además, es posible que el modelo esté dando una puntuación alta a “Volume monde” porque está relacionado con los términos “ventes” y “monde”